# How to plot Technical Analysis indicators in VectorBT

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, trading, ta-lib, back-testing

I am using the vectorbt library to run tests and visualize results.

I want to use the KeltnerChannel indicator. KeltnerChannel is only available in the Technical Analysis Library (TA).

I get a visual plotted when I call

```
vbt.BBANDS.run(close_price).plot().show()
```

But when I call the following

```
vbt.ta('KeltnerChannel').run(high=high_price, low=low_price, close=close_price).plot()
```

An error is thrown: *AttributeError: 'KeltnerChannel' object has no attribute 'plot'*

As a test, I tried plotting an indicator from TA-Lib. I get the same error. But, this example is from the documentation.

```
vbt.talib('MACD').run(btc.get('Close')).plot()
```

*'MACD' object has no attribute 'plot'*

The 'ta' and 'talib' indicators do run, they just don't plot.

I am able to plot basic vbt indicators, how can I plot ta and talib indicators?

I am using the community version and not the pro version of VectorBT.

Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

1. Create the indicator object:

```
keltnerIndicator = vbt.IndicatorFactory.from_ta('KeltnerChannel')
```

2. Calculate the indicator:

```
keltner = keltnerIndicator.run(high=prices.High, low=prices.Low, close=prices.Low)
```

3. Plot chart:

```
prices.Close.plot(figsize = (18, 9), title = 'Price Close and Channel Keltner')
keltner.keltner_channel_hband.plot()
keltner.keltner_channel_lband.plot()
keltner.keltner_channel_mband.plot();
```

Inside the created object, `keltner`, we have other methods. Signals trading and other.